# How to use lambda in DataFrame.assign to solve the ambiguity of truth value of Series?

Tags: pandas, lambda, python-3.5

I created a dataframe using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import exp
import random

moves = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4)]

data = {'moves': list(map(lambda i: moves[i] if divmod(i, len(moves))[0] != 1 else moves[divmod(i, len(moves))[1]],
                       [i for i in range(2 * len(moves))])),
    'player': list(map(lambda i: 1 if i >= len(moves) else 2,
                       [i for i in range(2 * len(moves))])),
    'wins': [random.randint(0, 2) for i in range(2 * len(moves))],
    'playout_number': [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(2 * len(moves))]
    }
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to add another column to dataframe using the code below:

```
total = sum(map(lambda a, b: exp(a/b) if b != 0 else 0, frame['wins'], frame['playout_number']))
frame = frame.assign(weight=lambda a: exp(a.wins/a.playout_number) / total if a.playout_number != 0 else 0)
```

when I used the code above I got this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I understand the reason for the error, But I don't know how to rewrite the lambda function to deal with the error. I want a function that if `frame['playout']` is not zero return `exp(frame['wins'] / frame['playout_number'])` and return zero if playout_number were zero.
Can you guys help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#use apply to create the new weight column.
frame['weight'] = frame.apply(lambda x: exp(x['wins'] / x['playout_number']) / total if x['playout_number'] !=0 else 0, axis=1)

frame
Out[117]: 
     moves  player  playout_number  wins    weight
0   (1, 2)       2               0     0  0.000000
1   (1, 3)       2               0     1  0.000000
2   (1, 4)       2               1     0  0.070885
3   (2, 1)       2               1     0  0.070885
4   (2, 3)       2               0     1  0.000000
5   (2, 4)       2               1     2  0.523774
6   (1, 2)       1               1     1  0.192686
7   (1, 3)       1               0     1  0.000000
8   (1, 4)       1               0     0  0.000000
9   (2, 1)       1               1     0  0.070885
10  (2, 3)       1               1     0  0.070885
11  (2, 4)       1               0     2  0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your simple and concise answer. Well done! Could you upvote the question? thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why `assign` doesn't work but `apply` does?